# Protobuf unmarshal arbitrary messages. Protobuf message polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, go, udp, protocol-buffers

There is a Go server that accepts messages over UDP. Using this design, it would be able to scan only one specific type of entity, `world.Entity`.

```
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, addr, err := pc.ReadFrom(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        packet := &service.Packet{}
        err = proto.Unmarshal(buf[:n], packet)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }

        log.Println(packet)

        go serve(pc, addr, buf[:n])
    }
```

How the design can be changed in a way that would allow sending different types of messages? The reasoning is to make this UDP server work like a REST API. Say there is a `world.Packet` message composed of an enum field and another field that can have different types of messages. The server checks the enum and depending on it, attempts to unmarshal the message, which can be of multiple types. Are there tools in Protobuf that would make this possible?

I realize that this is not the only solution. A simpler approach (but more verbose) is to make different kinds of messages for different "endpoints" (messages with different enum fields). Are there other solutions? Which one do you think is the best?

Comment: @MarcGravell this is perfect. Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In protobuf, look at `oneof`. With a single/common outer message with a `oneof` field, you can automatically handle all the expected inner types. Some protobuf implementations can represent this as polymorphism, although that isn't the default experience.